# Finding and removing some characters in a column of data in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, data-cleaning

I have copied and pasted some debugging information into an Excel sheet.

However, it contains some "weird" characters in some cells of one column, that should otherwise contain integers only. What would be the easiest way to eliminate such characters using VBA? An example is shown in the list below:

```
1 **'␁'** <- I'm trying to get rid of the part that I have bolded
2 '␂'
3 '␃'
4 '␂'
```

I want to use the file as a data source in another application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @stanigator: You should ask the questions in a way that does not presume others to know anything about your problem. I tried to re-formulate it to be easier to understand. Please correct it if I didn't quite hit the point.

Comment: Done; well done on the editing. Must thank you for making the phrasing sounding clearer. I've added a block of sample characters that I want to rid of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that worked for me, although it may not be very elegant:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ' Macro1 Macro
    Dim temp As String

    For u = 1 To 28000
        If Cells(u, 4) <> 0 Then
            Cells(u, 4).Select
            temp = Mid(ActiveCell.Text, 1, InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "'") - 1)
            Cells(u, 4) = temp
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (first time posting code here, so please bear with me;o). I believe I commented the VBA code enough, but any questions, just let me know.

```
' Replaces all the charaters in vaFind with strReplace
Sub FindAndReplace(ByVal vaFind As Variant, ByVal strReplace As String, ByVal rngToSearch As Range)
' vaFind is an array containing all the strings you want to replace
' strReplace is what you want to replace it with
' rngToSearch is the range you want to Find & Replace your characters
Dim x As Long
For x = LBound(vaFind, 1) To UBound(vaFind, 1)

  rngToSearch.Cells.Replace What:=vaFind(x), Replacement:=strReplace, _
      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next x

End Sub

' Now if you want to clean it automatically,
' Place the following code INTO any Sheets that you
' are have the debug data placed into.
' NOTE: prefix Asterick and question mark with a tilde to replace those characters "~*"
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Calls the FindAndReplace sub, and removes all:
' astericks, apostrophes and "Whatever Else You need cleaned"'s
' In this case, in column A
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
Call FindAndReplace(Array("~*", "'", "Whatever Else You need cleaned"), "", Me.Columns("A:A"))
End If
' NOTE: This sub will be called whenever the sheet changes, and only process column A
' You can customize which columns, too.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expressions might be easiest. I would use an ADO recordset and look through that.

**A few notes on RegEx**

```
''http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx
Dim objRegEx As RegExp
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Global = True

''This is a sample string, the field would go here
strText = "q@12""£c" 

''Find anything not a-z, 0-9
objRegEx.Pattern = "[^a-z0-9]"

''Replace with a dash, "" is fine too. 
strOut = objRegEx.Replace(strText, "-")
```

**A few notes on ADO and Excel**

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

strcn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" _
& strFile & ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"

cn.Open strcn

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", cn, 3 'adOpenStatic'
```

Comment: Because is uses RegEx on a problem that can be simple solved by built in methods of VBA! AND then uses ADO.NET to iterate through a excel worksheet!!!! Absolutly insane - if i could mark it down more, i would.

Comment: It is ADO, normal enough for MS applications, and the OP wants to use this data in another application, not unlikely as a recordset. RegEx will ensure that only numbers remain, without having to go through a list of possible characters. There are other examples of this type of approach on SO.

Answer (score -1):

As you are debugging - Are you really sure you want to remove them? They are ASCII control characters. But then again i don't know what you are debugging....

The characters you are seeing are unicode characters that represent the ascii control character - so wherever you have copied the data from has translated it for you.

standard excel function Clean is designed remove the ASCII control characters so wont work here.

But this will, it removes all the unicode characters in the CONTROL PICTURES range

```
Sub Macro1()
  ' Macro1 Macro
  '
  For u = 9210 To 9216 
     a = Cells.Replace(ChrW(u), "") ' replaces values in whole Worksheet
  Next
End Sub

' use this to replace the values in a single column only
' i cant test this at the moment as i don't have Excel handy...
...
   a = Range("A1:A2800").Replace(ChrW(u), "") ' replaces values in Col A
...
```

Comment: In order for me to copy and paste the same data in Matlab workspace, I would have to get rid of the funny characters, as I can't save the image as unsigned int8 rather than unsigned char (although they are the same in terms of precision and byte length).

Comment: This is the code that I have right now that tries to replace the weird characters

    Sub Macro1()
        ' Macro1 Macro
        
        For u = 1 To 28000
            a = Cells(u, 4).Replace(ChrW(u), "")
        Next
    End Sub

However, when I have 0 in the cell, the script would erase that zero. If I have something else as I have shown in my edited question, then it doesn't do anything. Are those unicode characters or are those really ASCII characters?

Comment: You are using u as both an index to the cells and as a character to replace. '0' is a character in that range of characters so it gets replaced. The character you see are actually Unicode characters from the CONTROL PICTURES section of Unicode. If you just want to replace the values in a single column then i think you need to use something like Range("A1:A28000").Replace(...) etc See the addition i've made to the code: